# how to set column width in table so the content adjust according to the width?

Tags: html, html-table

Here is the table

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped" id="sms_data">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="message">Message</th>
        <th>DELIVERED</th>
        <th>UNDELIVERED</th>
        <th>EXPIRED</th>
        <th>REJECTED</th>
        <th>TOTAL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- 160 character long message-->
        </td>
        <td> Number</td>
        <td> Number</td>
        <td> Number</td>
        <td> Number</td>
        <td> Number Total</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want the Message column to be around 20% width. So I tried this

```css
th.message {
    width: 20%;
}
```

But with this the content is over lapping on other columns...
I want the content in Message column to look like this

```
    Message with 160 
character around
```

Instead of this

```
    Message of 160 characters long
```

```
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Bootstrap is used to style all content.
Please help me how to do this? Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Normally it should not overlap. So some other css is making the issue which is hard to find with what you posted here. See https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-stonebraker-8tp8p

Comment: Can you post your all styles?

Comment: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 Bootstrap 3.3.7 is used to style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    .table{
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    td.message{
        overflow: hidden;
    } 
    td, th{
        white-space: initial !important;
    }
</style>
```

This solved my issue

Comment: If it solve it, you can accept your own answer :)